react-native webview ios javascript not working
I have completed the WebView setup for Android and am currently working on iOS.  On the WebView page, the following message is displayed:
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
It says that the script is not running. How should I resolve this issue?
I’m using Xcode and WebStorm as my development tools.
Here’s my WebView code:
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: myWebview }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true} 
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    scalesPageToFit={true} 
  />
</SafeAreaView>

Also, in Info.plist, I have already set the following permissions:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
  <true/>
</dict>


Can anyone help with this?

Looks like the latest release is broken: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/3616
